# shell script unable to set environment variable with the grepped value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the shell script, I want to grep a value from the log file and set as the value of one environment. In the log file, there is one line like this:

```
SOME_PATH=/some/specific/path
```

In my shell script, I grep the `SOME_PATH` keyword, and I got the above line and split it with `=`, but I'm now able to set the environment variable:

```
line=`grep "SOME_PATH" /path/to/the/log.log`
path=${line##*=} 
export SOME_PATH="$path"  #I cannot change the environment variable with this line.
```

And if I just have the script like below, the environment variable changes.

```
export SOME_PATH=/some/specific/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Exported variables available either in processes spawned from shell (script) which `export`ed a var or in another script with `source`d script with `export` statement.

1st way:

```
$ cat exp.sh
#!/bin/bash

export MYVAR="hi there"
bash
# or bash -c "echo here: $MYVAR"
```

2nd way:

```
$ cat exp.sh
#!/bin/bash

export MYVAR="hi there"

$ cat imp.sh
#!/bin/bash

. exp.sh

echo $MYVAR
```

Here's another explanation: [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#EXPORTREF).

Comment: Hi, I `sourced` the script when running, in your answer, I got error of `cat: exp.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's because you haven't created it ;)